# iPhone: available disk space

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am creating an audio-recording application and I need to know how much disk space is available (not ram).

How can I retrieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is 0kb always.  The iPhone has no hard drive.

Comment: It has no hard drive but it has a flash memory based file system which is logically the same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but since the iPhone is a UNIX based OS you should be able to get the free space on the flash file system using the [statfs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/statfs) system call (see link for documentation).

Just use as parameter the path to the app directory that you plan to write to.

Answer (score 4):

Best solution for me is to use the NSFileManager method:

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfFileSystemForPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

on the directory where you want to save your data. This is a wrapper around the `statfs` system call, as is mentioned in the docs. But if you're already using NSFileManager, this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a useful example.

http://kdbdallas.com/2008/12/27/maciphone-show-availble-useable-diskspace/