# iOS app out of memory handling

Tags: ios, file, memory

In an iOS application, I'm generating a 'voice recorder' functionality for continuous capturing of speech.

I use the following code for writing the speech in to a file.

```
//output speech
NSString *filePath = [root stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output_speech.raw"];
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    [[NSData data] writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:ptrOut length:DataByteSize];
NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
[handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];
[handle writeData:myData];
[handle closeFile];
```

My question is, in case the iOS device is going out of memory, how to handle the file writing situation?

Comment: Is your PROJECT ARC enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is ARC enabled. And I am writing the output file at the 'Documents' section of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Infinity James, I obtained the free space using the method mentioned in following link. [link] (http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-detect-total-available-free-72283.S.217861544)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar question here:

[iPhone: available disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249014/iphone-available-disk-space)

I would check for the available disk space and appropriately determine whether to cancel the write and alert the user, or to just silently fail.

Comment: Thanks, I obtained the free space using the method mentioned in following link. [link] (http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-detect-total-available-free-72283.S.217861544)